# Sanitize jQuery validation plugin data prior to validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Yes, I know that data sanitation and validation must be done server-side, but please stay with me.

Using the following script, `stackoverflow.com` will fail validation since a protocol is not given.  If a URL is inputted without a protocol, I wish to add a default protocol (http://) to the input value prior to client-side validation.  I don't wish to relax the validation method to silently accept URLs without a protocol as the user should be aware that a protocol was added.

How is this best accomplished?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                var validator=$("#myForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        url: {url:true,}
                    },
                });

                //Added per Monax's suggestion.
                $('#url').blur(function(){this.value=this.value.substring(0,4)=='http'?this.value:(this.value?'http://'+this.value:'');});;
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm" method="post">
            <input name="url" id="url" value="">
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <?php echo('<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>');?>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: The `url` rule is working as designed.  If you want the rule to work differently, you'll have to write your own.  However, if you don't want to "relax" the rule to accept the data you insist on feeding it, then not sure what you expect.

Comment: when does the validation execute? onsubmit?
you could write a function on blur to check for protocols. Despite that, I think you shouldn't be trying to push the user into protocols, if you know the problem, and it's easy to fix programatically, why bother the user? (just a thought)

Comment: @Sparky  I agree the `url`  rule is working as designed, and I don't wish to change it.  Prior to submission, I wish to update the input value.

Comment: Since the jQuery Validate plugin handles capturing the click of the submit and other triggering events, that is no trivial task.  My only suggestion would be to have two fields one visible that is not validated and one hidden that is validated.  You would copy and manipulate the data and programmatically trigger the validation.

Comment: @monxas.  You mean something like `$('#url').blur(function(){this.value='http://'+this.value;});` (obviously needs to be improved to test if a protocol was already specified).  Doing so will fail validation upon first pass.  On second thought, maybe not a bad thing....

Comment: @monxas idea will lead to trouble since the validation plugin will always interfere with that.

Comment: yeah, that was my approach. Another way could be using jQuery.validator.addMethod(), maybe getting the original code of the url validation and prepend the code that adds https:\\.  but maybe that's exactly what you meant when you talked about "not relaxing it"

Comment: @Sparky.  Why do you think it will be trouble?  Seems to work.  See updated code on original post (and also at http://jsbin.com/riwugoluxi/1/).  Yes, it will validate as an error upon first pass, but will pass after that.

Comment: @monxas  Yes, that is what I meant by "not relaxing it".

Comment: *"it will validate as an error upon first pass, but will pass after that."* ~ That is **not** the standard (or expected) behavior of this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to write a custom rule and you insist on manipulating the data before validation.  Your options are limited since the plugin is automatically capturing all the validation triggering events.  This is my suggested workaround.

1. Create two input fields...

   - one visible for the user (no validation)
   - one hidden for validation. (validation message presented though)
2. Upon entering any data into visible field, you would programmatically copy and modify the data as needed into the hidden field.
3. Then programmatically trigger validation on the hidden field.

Something like this.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="url" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#url').on('blur keyup', function() {
    var myurl = $(this).val(); // entered value

    // manipulate and sanitize the value as desired

    $('[name="url"]').val() = newvalue; // copy the new value into the hidden field.
    $('[name="url"]').valid(); // trigger validation on the hidden field
});
```

**NOTES**:

- You'll have to enable validation on hidden fields by properly setting [the `ignore` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) to something that allows it.  `[]` will enable validation on all hidden fields.
- You might have to use [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to tweak the placement of the error message for this hidden field.  You can do this conditionally.